# Gatsby wont transform jpg to Webp

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

what am i doing wrong so the JPG image is not been converted and optimized in webp?

it happens only in About component. Other components are optimized perfectly.

**It's my "About" component.**

code:

```js
imports...

const About = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      wordpressPage(wordpress_id: { eq: 47 }) {
        content
        featured_media {
          localFile {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(quality: 100, maxWidth: 1000) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <AboutWrapper>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div
            className="col-md-6 aboutImage"
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `url(${
                data.wordpressPage.featured_media.localFile.childImageSharp
                  .fluid.src
              })`
            }}
          />
          <div className="col-md-6 aboutText">
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.wordpressPage.content }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </AboutWrapper>
  )
}

export default About
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the Gatsby fragment you're using in your query returns a bunch of fields, including `src`, `srcSet`, and `srcSetWebp`. The WebP formatted images are going to be in `srcSetWebp`, but this field is meant to be passed to an `img` or `source` tag (i.e. a DOM element) and not as CSS.

By only using `fluid.src` you wind up with just a single image in the original format.

Comment: Thank you Corey! can you indicate a way for me to solve one problem? Images inserted in the content of single posts (wordpress) are not sent to Gatsby post (static folder). https://imgur.com/gallery/BILwnkJ